# Close a window on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to close a tab or window by clicking on a button in JQuery? I tried window.close() thinking that it would close that window,but it doesn't seem to work. Someone help me.

```
<?php echo $javascript->link('jquery');?>
<script type="java/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".close").click(function(){ 
                    window.close();
            });
    });
</script>
<div class="close">
   <?php echo $form->button('Close Window');?>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

Sorry,The code is correct. The answer didn't come due to a very silly mistake of mine.
I had typed script type as java/javascript instead of text/javascript.Now I have changed it and this works fine.

Comment: type="java/javascript"?  That's should be "text/javascript"

Comment: sorry that was careless mistake..

Comment: yeh.. you are right..
It was a very silly mistake of mine..
Sorry to bother everyone..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As seth comments, your problem is the handler not being attached because the browser won't execute java/javascript code as it doesn't know what to do with it (since it is nothing). Change it to text/javascript and you should be fine.

Comment: yeh.. you are right..
It was a very silly mistake of mine..
Sorry to bother everyone..

Answer (score 3):

There is actually a function [`codeBlock`](http://api.cakephp.org/class/javascript-helper#method-JavascriptHelpercodeBlock) in `JavascriptHelper` that inserts a well-formed JavaScript script tag for you, including the CDATA section delimiters. Used together with [PHP's heredoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) I think it's a quite neat solution. At least it spares you from tiresome mistakes like these. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

`<a href="javascript:window.open('','_self').close();">close</a>`

Answer (score -1):

If the browser window is not opened by the Javascript, it can not be closed by the script.

Comment: Well. It can, it's just that most browsers will ask the user first.

Answer (score -1):

You put the click event on the div, not on the button.